# Writing a parallel programming framework, what have I missed?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-2.x

**Clarification**: As per some of the comments, I should clarify that this is intended as a simple framework to allow execution of programs that are *naturally* parallel (so-called embarrassingly parallel programs). It isn't, and never will be, a solution for tasks which require communication or synchronisation between processes.

I've been looking for a simple process-based parallel programming environment in Python that can execute a function on multiple CPUs on a cluster, with the major criterion being that it needs to be able to execute unmodified Python code. The closest I found was [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/), but pp does some pretty funky things, which can cause the code to not be executed in the correct context (with the appropriate modules imported etc).

I finally got tired of searching, so I decided to write my own. What I came up with is actually quite simple. The problem is, I'm not sure if what I've come up with is simple because I've failed to think of a lot of things. Here's what my program does:

- I have a job server which hands out jobs to nodes in the cluster.
- The jobs are handed out to servers listening on nodes by passing a dictionary that looks like this:

  ```
  {
  'moduleName':'some_module', 
  'funcName':'someFunction', 
  'localVars': {'someVar':someVal,...}, 
  'globalVars':{'someOtherVar':someOtherVal,...}, 
  'modulePath':'/a/path/to/a/directory', 
  'customPathHasPriority':aBoolean, 
  'args':(arg1,arg2,...), 
  'kwargs':{'kw1':val1, 'kw2':val2,...}
  }
  ```
- `moduleName` and `funcName` are mandatory, and the others are optional.
- A node server takes this dictionary and does:

  ```
  sys.path.append(modulePath)
  globals()[moduleName]=__import__(moduleName, localVars, globalVars)
  returnVal = globals()[moduleName].__dict__[funcName](*args, **kwargs)
  ```
- On getting the return value, the server then sends it back to the job server which puts it into a thread-safe queue.
- When the last job returns, the job server writes the output to a file and quits.

I'm sure there are niggles that need to be worked out, but is there anything obvious wrong with this approach? On first glance, it seems robust, requiring only that the nodes have access to the filesystem(s) containing the .py file and the dependencies. Using `__import__` has the advantage that the code in the module is automatically run, and so the function should execute in the correct context.

Any suggestions or criticism would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I should mention that I've got the code-execution bit working, but the server and job server have yet to be written.

Comment: This is mighty ambitious. Can you turn this into a question?

Comment: @katriealex: No, pp most definitely does not do what I want. I spent weeks trying to shoehorn my program into pp's paradigm and kept running into bug after bug. pp has some very strange issues. For example, several failures with `import` statements occur deep within the numpy libraries for no apparent reason. I think the problem is that pp tries to execute the function in a "clean" environment and expects you to explicitly specify all modules that your code is dependent on, what setup code needs to be called, etc. Writing trivial programs with pp is easy, writing non-trivial ones is _hard_.

Comment: Sounds a bit like grid computing. You looked around for some python grid solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what the place for it would be, but could you explain more about why pp doesn't do what you want?  I'm confused by your comment; does pp work differently than what you want, or does it fail to work as advertised?  I'm stewing over some pp code right now, would love to hear more about its problems and how it works.   Edit: I know what the right place would be; another question!  I'll ask it right now.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: Yes, I have and found all the ones listed on python.org unsatisfactory. However, @luispedro's answer looks promising. @Thomas: pp works more or less as advertised. Basically, my problem with pp is that it's not easy to take an existing serial program and parallelize it, even if the problem can naturally be broken into bits. As you're finding out (from reading your questions), pp is _very_ particular about passing the correct `depmods` and `depfuncs`, when it really has no need to be. Add to that the fact that I ran into some actual bugs, and I just lost patience with it.

Comment: @Thomas: To me, it seems like pp duplicates a lot of functionality that it can just ask the Python interpreter to do. I think that is the root of the problems I've had with pp.

Comment: Writing nontrivial parallel programs in *any* programming langauge, let alone ones that perform well, is hard.  Are you sure the problem is the framework, and not the task you are trying to do?

Comment: Writing non-trivial shared-data parallel programs is _hard_, writing _shared nothing_ programs isn't (or shouldn't be) particularly hard to achieve.

Comment: This would require that the function be a top level function in the module, correct?

Comment: Yes, it would. It's easy enough to write a module with a `main()` function though...

Comment: @Chinmay: Shared nothing programs still have the same synchronization problems that shared-memory programs have, and they have another problem on top: is the data I'm holding up to date? Parallel programming problems generally require you process the data in organized ways, and that gets you crossways with respect to the parallelization. Rarely do you encounter applications which are perfectly embarassingly parallel (which is what you seem to imply "shared-nothing" means). If the programs have any need to interact/synchronize, "shared nothing" means you pay a high communcation cost to boot.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: This is a solution for embarrassingly parallel programs, essentially making things a bit easier for developers. This solves problems like having to write each process' output to a separate file to ensure output integrity. I'm _not_ trying to write an easy solution for problems that are not naturally parallel. Better people than me have tried and failed at that. However, Python doesn't seem to have a solution for embarrassingly parallel problems that "just works", which is what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Chinmay: Aha.  You should probably clarify that in your question (and maybe even in the header).  It sure put me off the scent :-{

Comment: The job server (in your approach and also in jug) might become a bottleneck if there are many cluster nodes.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks! That is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Mind you, this is also true for `pp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have actually written something that probably satisfies your needs: [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug). If it does not solve your problems, I promise you I'll fix any bugs you find.

The architecture is slightly different: workers all run the same code, but they effectively generate a similar dictionary and ask the central backend "has this been run?". If not, they run it (there is a locking mechanism too). The backend can simply be the filesystem if you are on an NFS system.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I'll take a look and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Unfortunately, since jug controls the launching of the workers, it isn't a good solution for me. The cluster I primarily use uses Sun GridEngine to schedule jobs and I can't allow processes to be spawned outside the SGE scheduler.

Comment: It should actually work. You just launch "jug execute" jobs with the SGE scheduler (it's actually the setup I use personally!). It even works if the jobs start at different times.

Comment: Alright, I must have misunderstood the documentation. I haven't really had the time to give it the attention it deserves, been working on something else...

Comment: Sorry about the bounty, but I assumed if there wasn't a better answer, it would go to you. That's the way it used to be. I'm going to accept your answer anyway...

Answer (score 5):

I myself have been tinkering with batch image manipulation across my computers, and my biggest problem was the fact that some things don't easily or natively pickle and transmit across the network.

for example: pygame's surfaces don't pickle. these I have to convert to strings by saving them in StringIO objects and then dumping it across the network.

If the data you are transmitting (eg your arguments) can be transmitted without fear, you should not have *that* many problems with network data.

Another thing comes to mind: what do you plan to do if a computer suddenly "disappears" while doing a task? while returning the data? do you have a plan for re-sending tasks?

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking of basically polling each node every "x" seconds and if a node doesn't answer "y" consecutive polls, to either send the job to the first node that finishes or alternatively spawn a new server process on a different node (which alternative to take will be specified by the user). I will also need a sensible way to handle errors and/or exceptions that occur on the nodes.

Comment: How to handle "unpicklable" arguments is a good question, and one that I suspect doesn't have a general answer. It might be a good idea to write a base handler that simply unpickles arguments, but allowing it to be subclassed for special cases.